# CSS2 DIV Presentation Issue

Tags: css, html, css-float

I need to create a page that has quotes side-by-side for a large number of rows.I am looking for a clean CSS2 presentation where the quotes of each row line up vertically and don't run below each other.Also, I am looking for a solution with the least amount of code and preferably one that doesn't float DIVs and does utilize the display attribute.

Re: the code below, my thinking is to contain each quote in its own DIV (in hopes to have the quotes of one row display side-by-side) and have the DIVs of one row be contained by a parent DIV (in hopes of having the quotes in the next row line up vertically).  shred the code apart.Start a new.Do whatever you need to let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    body

    {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:11px;
    }

    div#mainContainer

    {
        width:570px;
    }


    div#mainContainer div.subContainer
    {
        margin:30px;
    }

    div#mainContainer div.subContainer div 
    {
        vertical-align:top;
        width:285px;
    }

    div#mainContainer div.subContainer div.contentLeft
    {
        float:left;
        margin-right:45px;
    }

    div#mainContainer div.subContainer div.contentRight
    {
        display:inline;
    }

</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="subContainer">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut."
            <p>Bill, New York</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            "Labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation." 
            <p>Fred, Detroit</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subContainer">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            "Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint."
            <p>Sarah, Seattle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            "Occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut."
            <p>Phil, Austin</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subContainer">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            "Labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad."
            <p>Jon, Petrolia</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            "Minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia."
            <p>Chris, Burlington</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:11px;
    }

    #mainContainer {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .quoteBox {
        width: 300px; /* Half the width of the mainContainer to ensure there is always space to exactly TWO quotes on each row */
        float: left;
    }

    .clearer {
        height: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        clear: both; /* Clear the line to ensure no quotes end up partly below another one. Follow the pattern: Two quotes, clear, two quotes, clear etc... */
    }

    blockquote,cite { margin: 12px }

</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut."</blockquote>
            <cite>Bill, New York</cite>
        </div>

        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation." </blockquote>
            <cite>Fred, Detroit</cite>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>   

        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint."</blockquote>
            <cite>Sarah, Seattle</cite>
        </div>

        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut."</blockquote>
            <cite>Phil, Austin</cite>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>   

        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad."</blockquote>
            <cite>Jon, Petrolia</cite>
        </div>

        <div class="quoteBox">
            <blockquote>"Minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia."</blockquote>
            <cite>Chris, Burlington</cite>
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this, for example? Reduced the number of excess DIV-elements a bit, plus cleaned the CSS a little. Looks cleaner, and should work the way you described your problem.

blockquote and cite-elements used to add semantic meanings to the document.

Answer (score 0):

without deviating much from your original elements (although the suggestion that you add semantic meaning to inner elements is good), I got success by replace your  element with this:

```
body
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}

div#mainContainer
{
    width: 645px;
}

div.subContainer
{
    margin: 30px;
}

div.subContainer div
{
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    width: 285px;
}

div.contentLeft
{
    margin-right: 45px;
}
```

Note that your calculations on widths were too low. I tested this with IE8, not FF, but it should work. If you are using IE8, there's a new very powerful Developer Toolbar built in, which includes a Layout pane that shows effective Offset, Margin, Border, and Padding values on all sides of an element.